# Getting back multiple lookup fields with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table contract looks like this:

[image]

The `item_id` here is a primary key which is used as a foreign one on `Contract_attr`:

[image]

I want to return 2 columns one is the contract# (0000000903) and each of the ATTR_Val for field_id = 238 and field_id = 326 (N, N).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT distinct [CONTRACT].item_name, [CONTRACT_ATTR].ATTR_VAL
FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT] 
JOIN [CONTRACT_ATTR]
ON [CONTRACT].item_name = [CONTRACT_ATTR].ATTR_VAL AND [CONTRACT_ATTR].item_id = 17
```

The 17 will be dynamic in practice. But with this query I am getting back the contract# two times:

[image]

Edit: also If I add `AND [CONTRACT_ATTR].field_id in (238, 326)` I get back nothing.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the fields in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT CO.item_name, CA.ATTR_VAL
FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT] CO
JOIN [CONTRACT_ATTR] CA ON CA.Item_Id = CO.Item_Id
WHERE CA.Item_Id = 17 AND CA.field_id in (238, 326)
```

In the `ON` clause you were used the `item_name` and `ATTR_VAL` for matching. It returns the wrong result.